# Angular2 Webpack bundle single module

Tags: angular, module, npm, webpack, bundle

I have a Webpack Angular 2 project and I would like to bundle a single module directory. The purpose of this is to load the module on npm and be included in other Angular2 projects. The default bundling behaviour is to bundle the entire project.

How would I achieve this?